# Authentication Prompt is Looping Forever on Website Hosted on Internal Server in IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, windows, windows-authentication, iis-8

I've created a plain HTML file in a newly created web site in IIS. Also, I've disabled anonymous authentication and I've enabled windows authentication.

I'm trying to authenticate using a domain user (the whole hosting machine is a server inside a domain) and whenever I fill the user and password in the windows authentication prompt, it requests it again, and again, and again...

Sadly I can't figure out why this isn't working. I've also tried with a domain administrator user, and I get the same result.

What am I missing here? Do I need to perform some additional step to allow domain users in the whole IIS web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying this on the local system hosting the site?  If so, you are likely running into the loopback check.  Please [see my answer to a similar question](https://serverfault.com/a/485011/20148).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try accessing the page through the FQDN of the server?. Are you getting any errors in the Windows event log regarding Windows Authentication?

You can enable Failed Request Tracing module to log the entire flow the request with the error condition.