# Site Hosted in IIS7 Continuously Prompting with Windows Authentication

Tags: web-server, iis-7, windows-authentication, intranet

I've read most of the articles posted about this topic already and nothing has resolved this issue, so I figured it was time to post.

I have an intranet site that uses Windows Authentication within our network.  Everything was working fine for a few months, but all of a sudden when I came back from the weekend it will prompt users forever to enter their username & password.  Even if you use valid credentials it will not work.  An error message is never shown, even if you cancel the prompt (which will keep asking for credentials forever).  Tracing shows that a 401.1 is being returned, but I can guarantee that valid credentials are being sent.  I don't understand 1) why it's prompting in the first place and 2) why it won't accept credentials anymore.

Here are the the steps that I've taken this far:

- Made sure that NTLM is first in the provider list
- Made sure that Anon auth is disabled
- [Disable of loopback](https://serverfault.com/a/485011/195235)
- Rebooting

I have also made sure that there are no Authentication Failures in the audit Security log.  I did enable Failed Request Tracing and the only thing I see in the logs related to Windows Authentication is a message saying:

> no credentials are available in the security package

However, many articles mention that this has to do with Kerberos, which I don't even have as a provider, so I'm not sure what this is referring.

Any ideas?  I can post the tracing logs if you guys want.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is actually a bug with Server 2008 R2 when connected to a domain and either the password of the identity of the application pool is changed or the computer password itself is changed.  This causes all authentication methods to fail due to the following cause by Microsoft:

> This issue occurs because a flag is set in a global credential incorrectly after the computer password is changed.  Therefore, authentication fails after the IIS service is restarted.

The resolution is provided as a hotfix from Microsoft.  Here is the link to the KB article as well as where the hotfix can be downloaded:  [Users cannot access an IIS-hosted website after the computer password for the server is changed in Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2545850)